# CNAME and TXT record for same subdomain not working

Tags: dns, cname

I need to add a TXT record for the subdomain test.domain.com in the zone file. In this zone file there is an existing CNAME for the same subdomain. The two records looking like this:

```
test IN CNAME asdf.someotherdomain.com. 
test IN TXT "Some text i need to add"
```

But when I try to save this I get an error:

```
dns_master_load: :45: test.domain.com: CNAME and other data
zone domain.com/IN: loading from master file  failed: CNAME and other data
zone domain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
status: FAIL
```

It works if I do it with different subdomains, for example:

```
test IN CNAME asdf.someotherdomain.com. 
testing IN TXT "Some text i need to add"
```

I'm not exactly the best there is when it comes to DNS. Is it not possible to have the same subdomain in this scenario? Or am I missing something?

The servers are running bind.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Yeah that seems to it. That RFC could be a good thing to read.